# Get Employee ID from Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the user name and the employee ID from Azure Active Directory, but I keep getting a can not match parameter error. See the attached image.

```
Get-AzADUser -UserPrincipalName $.UserPrincipalName -EmployeeID $.EmployeeID
```

[Parameter Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6G7s.jpg)

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get the employeeId using AdditionalProperties.

Quickest way for me is using the azuread module, as employeeId is not a standard property but and extension, you can get that info using the following command:

```
get-azureaduser -objectid user@domain | get-azureaduserextension
```

[1]:Example https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAxz7.png

Also I recommend using graph API to get info from AAD.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/getting-started-with-graph-api-and-graph-explorer/?msclkid=249a6a28ae7311ec958ae49c7dc811e2

BR

Comment: This was useful it gives one, but better then none. I will just do it the old fashion way and look at each record one by one.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

***As there is no parameter called `EmployeeId` in the `get-azaduser` that's why it gives you the error . The employee Id is stored inside the additional properties.***

**So if you want to get the AD users name and employee ID you can use the below command :**

```
Get-AzADUser | Select-Object UserprincipalName , @{N="EmployeeId";E={$_.AdditionalProperties["employeeId"]} }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This was useful except it didn't output the Employee IDs. I will just do it the old fashion way and look at each record one by one.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I needed to grab this attribute and finally got it working:

```
$user = Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $displayName
$empID = $user.ExtensionProperty.employeeId
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32029101)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below and it worked for me.

```
Get-AzureADUser -top 70000 | ? {$_.AccountEnabled -like $true -and $_.userType -like "Member" -and $_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -notlike $null } |
select DisplayName,AccountEnabled,Userprincipalname,usertype,@{N="EmployeeID";E={$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId}}
```